# Redo earlier edit operation

Tags: undo-redo

This is a newbie's question, so please be patient if I do not use the right terms.

I know I can use "." to redo my last edit operation. But, is there a way to redo the one just before that?

Comment: it doesn't seem like as per http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36719/repeat-the-nth-last-command-in-vim .. there might some clever tricks available or to add something to vimrc.. I would recommend to use macro

Comment: No you can't. Use recordings for that.

Comment: If "the one just before that" was an ex command, you could have a look at `q:` (search would be `q/`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, this feature is not possible in vim right now. Although it's apparently a popular request, as many people have [asked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36719/repeat-the-nth-last-command-in-vim) the [same thing](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/2mniws/does_vim_have_a_last_edit_history_eg_3_to_redo/).

I did find this [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_use/CZ8KYt1i9BM) from two years ago on the vim mailing group. Bram Moolenaar (The founder, inventor, head developer, and current maintainer of vim) chimed in, and mentioned the possibility of a function `keyhistory(n)` where `n` is how far back to look.

> Plugins having to install a lot of maps to be able to know what was 
>   typed before the key that triggers an action is clumsy.
>
> How about Vim keeping a list of the last N typed keys? 
>   Suppose there is a function keyhistory(1), where the argument is how far 
>   back you look.
>
> I wonder how that would be used in a plugin.

So while *theoretically* this feature might be eventually implemented, I wouldn't hold your breath. The best alternative would be to use a macro as [romainl suggested.](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8988/redo-earlier-edit-operation#comment15568_8988)